# PHP Multi Dim Array to Javascript (with keys)

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a multi dimensional PHP array into Javascript.

I have created an array as shown...

```
foreach ($results as $row)
{
$template[] = array('Id'=>$row["Id"],'Address'=>$row["Addr"]),'name'=>$row["name"]);
}
```

I have tried using the PHP implode function to build the JS array ..
`var theJSTemplateArray = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $template).'"' ?>];`

The webpage fails to run so clearly a bug .. but I cant find it.
Is it because PHP implode does not work with multi-dim arrays..?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `json_encode` instead, `implode` is not used to handle multi-dimensional arrays. `$jsTemplateArray = json_encode($template);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233159/2943403

Comment: Black Mage @Chris Please flag to close duplicate questions instead of commenting the resolving advice.  This helps to prevent unneeded answers from being posted.  Duplicate questions which receive answers are not automatically removed by the Roomba.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the `implode()` function is designed for one-dimensional arrays, and therefore won't work as you would like with a multi-dimensional array.

To convert a multi-dimensional PHP array to a JS array you can use `json_encode()`. This will convert the PHP array into a JSON string, which JS can then interpret as an array or object:

```
var theJSTemplateArray = <?php echo json_encode($template); ?>;
```

How to get the array values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theJSTemplateArray.length; i++) {
    console.log("Id: " + theJSTemplateArray[i].Id);
    console.log("Address: " + theJSTemplateArray[i].Address);
    console.log("Name: " + theJSTemplateArray[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Please flag to close duplicate questions instead of answering them. (Virtually all basic questions asked in 2023 are duplicates.)